How to use redirect to navigate between 2 route groups
I organize my project folder as below:


          app
          
(app)

dashboard

page.tsx

page.tsx
layout.tsx

(auth)

login

page.tsx

register

page.tsx

page.tsx
layout.tsx




I am able to navigate between login and register by using redirect (from next/navigation). But I cannot redirect to dashboard as well as cannot redirect from dashboard to login or register.
P/s: I am able to navigate by using useRouter().push, but I want to use redirect because the redirect logic is on server actions.
P/s: when redirect is executed, the log from my terminal said that POST / 303 and nothing happen
Updated code that I redirect from "/" to login page
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default function Root({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
      return (
        <div>
          <form
            action={async () => {
              "use server";
              redirect("/login");
            }}
          >
            <button>Go to login</button>
          </form>
          <p>Root Page</p>
        </div>
      );
    }


Could add some code for example? To see how you use the redirect function at least.

@Invulner I added my example code. Please take a look

Here's how you can modify your Root component to redirect to the login page when the button is clicked:
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Root({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = () => {
    router.push('/login');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to login</button>
      <p>Root Page</p>
    </div>
  );
}

If you want to perform a server-side redirect, you would need to do it in getServerSideProps or getInitialProps. Here's an example of how you can do a server-side redirect in getServerSideProps:
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/login',
      permanent: false,
    },
  }
}

This will redirect all requests for this page to the login page. Note that this is a server-side redirect, so it will happen before the page is sent to the client.
